# edeliver can't receive ping from deployed node

Tags: elixir, edeliver

I have an application that works and can be deployed just fine. I'm trying to connect from one Node to another on a different machines, and for that I needed to change the `-name` property from `myapp@127.0.0.1` to `myapp@1.1.1.1` (the real IP).

I can connect via `Node.connect()` and it works fine, but `mix edeliver version staging` can't connect anymore to the Node. The error is `response: Node myapp@1.1.1.1 is not running!`. If I revert back to `myapp@127.0.0.1` it starts working, but that way I can't connect to the node.

I've tried to debug, but I can't go deeper into.

```
# Ensures the current node is running, otherwise fails
require_live_node() {
    if ! nodetool "ping" >/dev/null; then
        fail "Node $NAME is not running!"
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Am I missing something ? I've already have the ports necessary for Node connection open, but when it is 127.0.0.1 works fine, I don't think the issue is about that.

Comment: Did you set a `--cookie` for the (deployed) node?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the name. If I change for the real IP I can connect to my node via other node, but edeliver doesn't ping the machine.